# Date range in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I apply a date range to my query, is there anyway to display the dates used in the date range even if there is no data at those dates?

Suppose I use,

```
... where date between '1/12/2010' and '31/12/2010' order by date
```

What I want in my result is to show sum of all amount column until 1/12/2010 on that day even if there is no data for that date and also same for 31/12/2010.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Join with [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to fill in the gaps.

Example:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS today;
SELECT
    COUNT(foo.*),
    generate_series::date
FROM
    foo
        RIGHT JOIN generate_series('2010-12-18', '2010-12-25', interval '1 day') ON generate_series = today
GROUP BY
    generate_series;
```

Result:

```
0,'2010-12-18'
0,'2010-12-19'
1,'2010-12-20'
0,'2010-12-21'
0,'2010-12-22'
0,'2010-12-23'
0,'2010-12-24'
0,'2010-12-25'
```